# OS-X:ViewControllerからAppDelegateに変数の値を渡したい。

Tags: swift, macos

OS-Xのアプリをswiftで作成したいのですがViewControllerからAppDelegateに値を渡す方法がわかりません。

AppDelegateのapplicationWillTerminage(aNotification:NSNotification)に値を受け取りたいです。

AppDelegate Classで var Flag: Int? のような形で宣言してこのクラス変数を利用したいのですがViewController側でその値をセットさせる方法がわかりません。

以上、宜しくお願いします。

Comment: `AppDelegate`の`applicationWillTerminage(〜`は、`applicationWillTerminate(〜`のスペルミスですか？

Answer (score 1):

iOSでは、`UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate`で、`AppDelegate`のインスタンスを参照できますが、それはOS Xも同様です。

```
NSApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as? AppDelegate
```

これで参照できます。

> AppDelegate Classで var Flag: Int? のような形で宣言してこのクラス変数を利用したいのですが

Swiftは、Objective-Cとおなじく、**インスタンス変数**はあっても、**クラス変数はない**と思いましたが……
Swiftは、変数をできるだけOptional型にしないのが、ひとつのテクニックです。
Swiftの命名規則に従って、変数は小文字から始めましょう。

```
var flag: Int = 0
```

初期値を与えておけば、非Optional型にすることができ、いちいち!や?をつけずに使うことができます。

**おまけ：**

`AppDelegate`は、Responder Chainの経路に入っているので、`target`を`nil`にしたActionは、経路の途中にActionメソッドを記述していなければ、`AppDelegate`クラスに書いたActionメソッドで受け取ることができます。